# Finance the land on a non-financeable house?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, financing

A local real estate listing that I'm interested in says the house is non-financeable(it is an old mobile). However, it is on an acre of land. I have 20000 to put down, and I was wondering if it's possible to finance the land only, making up for the value gap with my down payment?

The land is a private property not part of a larger development, the entire acre is one parcel.

Comment: Can you add the country tag.

Answer (score 1):

Some lenders will make loans for vacant land, others will not. You have to discuss with local bank what are your plan for the land: live in the old mobile home; install a new mobile home; build a new house; Sell it to a developer; use it for camping...

Is the property part of a development with other mobile homes? If so there may be complications regarding the use and rights of the property. Some local jurisdictions also want to eliminate mobile homes, so they may put limitations on the housing options.